# C++: C1083: 'afxwin.h': No such file or directory - VS2010 with VC6 daffodil

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, window

Problem:

- If I include afxwin.h or atlbase.h, I get a C1083 ( no such file or directory)

Language:

- c++

Tools in use:

- Building in VS2010 Professional
- using daffondil to use the VS6 Toolchain/buildchain
- having installed VC6 Professional

Comment: Watch out, that the important part is the professional VS-Version. All errors reported on <put favourite place here> regarding the free VS version, that does indeed not include afxwin.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solve the Problem:**

check / correct the paths for ATL- and MFC-Includes at:
Project -> Properties -> Include Directories

**What might be wrong**
In your D:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props (or other Property-Sheets), the Include Directories-Property might have been overwritten.

**Background-Knowledge**
VS6 used to split ATL and MFC into two different paths:

- VC98\ATL\include
- VC98\MFC\include

In VS2010 the basic path to ATL or MFC is

- VC\atlmfc\include

So it might be, that in your project $(VSInstDir)atlmfc is set, instead of the two separated paths. If you correct that, everything should work fine.